# ASP MVC Routes being ignored in hybrid classic asp site

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp-classic, routes

I have an existing classic asp /asp mvc hybrid app. Which is slowly becoming less classic asp and more asp mvc. On the whole this works fine. However one sticking point is that the mvc routing fails when there is an existing folder that matches the route url.

For example there is an existing page on the path `[siteroot]\account\personaldetails\billing.asp` this is normally served on the url http://host.com/account/personaldetails/billing I have removed the asp file and have built an asp mvc view to replace it.

My routing works fine if the account folder is completely removed from the application, but if the account folder is there when I try to visit the new view I get a 404. How can I get around this?

Comment: I believe that how you have configured (enabled) your routing must be affecting this. For routing to work, the path must be handled by ASP.NET pipeline - which I suspect does not happen when account folder exists. Perhaps, you need to add special entries so that extension less paths under account folder are explicitly handled by ASP.NET while those with .asp handled by classic ASP extension. This may help you (for IIS 6): http://haacked.com/archive/2010/12/22/asp-net-mvc-3-extensionless-urls-on-iis-6.aspx. You should also post IIS version and how are you doing routing etc for better answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the rewrite rule I had in place was being to aggressive. I simply had to add a condition to prevent the newsletter being picked up as a .asp file.

```
<rule name="account remove extension">
    <match url="^account(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="newsletter(.*)$" negate="true" />
     </conditions>
     <action type="Rewrite" url="account/{R:1}.asp" />
</rule>
```